# What is this notation style called?

Tags: notation

I was reading a [paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013vitek-2013524.pdf) about implementing the statistical programming language R on the JVM, and encountered this notation I haven't seen before (I'm not formally CS-trained). What is the name of notational style? I've seen it before in other papers--usually as it related to functional programming and the REPL.
[image]

Comment: See [here1](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~pkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/s3_1.pdf) and [Backus-Naur form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

Comment: I had seen BNF before (Odersky did it in the Functional Programming Coursera), but usually it was written out into words, so I figured this was something different. Please paste your comment into a full answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I believe that the fraction notation for rules of inference was introduced by [R. Smullyan, _Theory of Formal Systems,_ 1961]. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system as a starting point.

Comment: actually, the fractional notation was used already in Gentzen's paper (1934) on natural deduction and sequent calculus, which I think (but am not 100% sure) is the original source.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, sorry. Smullyan also said so here, in comments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8VBeGl9Law I had rather badly misinterpreted a remark in another paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is notation for [Formal Proofs](http://www.ams.org/notices/200811/tx081101370p.pdf) and specification of language grammar in [Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

Answer (score 0):

The individual statements of the form $A\Rightarrow B$ are **sequents** and the things that look like fractions are **inference rules**.